# Get GUI name for different settings in neovim

Tags: vimrc, neovim, gvim

I am deciding between using either goneovim vs neovide, both on windows, but each uses the font height differently, so I a wanted to make something like:

```
if has(goneovim)
    "goneovim specific stuff
elseif has (neovide)
    "neovide specific stuff
end
```

So I want to know if that is possible, and if so, how I can get the name of the GUI in vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you're looking for is the following;

```
if exists('g:gonvim_running')
    "goneovim specific stuff
elseif exists('g:neovide')
    "neovide specific stuff
end
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! How did you find this information? Do those nvim front-ends document that they expose these variables? If so, that would be valuable information to [edit] in

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is exactly what I needed! Thanks, it works flawlessly.
And out of curiosity, how did you get that information?

Answer (score 1):

1. Neovim **IS NEITHER** GVim **NOR** Vim. Especially, when we talk about ui attachment.
2. In Neovim ui is implemented using client-server achitecture. That is, one Neovim core could be shared between any number (including zero if running builtin TUI) of external (G)UIs at the same time.
3. Strictly speaking, you ought to walk through `:h nvim_list_uis()` and `:h nvim_list_chans()` to honour item (2), but, if doing it *really* dirty

```
:echo nvim_get_chan_info(1).client.name
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I tried the `nvim_get_chan_info(1).client.name` it only works for the default neovim-qt, but not for other implementations, so I guess they are not sending back the data for nvim to capture. So I am assuming that it is impossible at the current state. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @kishikaisei Yes, that information is optional and its availability depends on client implementation. See `:h nvim_get_chan_info()` and `:h nvim_set_client_info()`.